# 5-6 duplicate calendar items

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have the same appointment 5-6 times throughout my calendar on Samsung Galaxy 3.  I merge 3 separate accounts onto my calendar.  This has never been a problem before.  If I try to "clean it up", I end up canceling meetings.  I tried uninstalling the calendar but same thing happened when I reinstalled it.  Any ideas?

Comment: The data for the calendar is probably backed up to Google, so you end up with multiple "Person x's birthday" entries etc. I have had this issue for years now and the only way I've found is to start deleting things, and that does not suit. I hope someone has a more elegant solution to this.

Comment: Thanks RossC - it is really frustrating to have to week through all those entries everyday.